# visual studio code pylance search folders

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have a project with some python in it - the python is part of a larger thing - there are several programs in several directories inside a root git - and there is some common code in yet another directory.

Running works fine - but pylance in visual studio code sees all of the dependencies as errors, even though most are in the current directory of the script I'm editing.  If I open that subdirectory they work fine - but I really want to have visual code open at the larger project level.

Is there any way to bung a file somewhere in the directory that tells pylance "here is the python search path" or something?

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Kindly let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: sorry - when i first saw the answer - i thought settings were a global thing - which was pointless to me, as it has to work for the whole team - I just read it more carefully and realised you can put this in a settings.json in your workspace - did that and it worked great.   So thanks heaps!

Comment: You're welcome. Seems I should post a clearer answer next time :D

Comment: no my fault - didn't read clearly enough and just made assumptions that settings were at the pylance level not at the workspace level

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may search for settings about `additional import search resolution paths`:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path1",
    "path2",
],
```

Please have a try.

More information view [Pylance Settings and Customization](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release#settings-and-customization).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer, but with GUI:

1. press *Ctrl*+*,* to get into setting search
2. write in the search bar extrapaths
3. in the *Python->Analysys: Extra Paths* item - press *Add Item*
4. Add your path (I used full path)